# Android Studio doesn't see static in debugger: no such static field

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

Strange thing, didn't find any info about this issue. In Watches window I have to replace static fields (for example, final ints) with numbers to debug, because Android Studio doesn't see them. But if I move mouse over them in code with ctrl pressed - it shows the value.

For example, myArray[IDX_SOMEINDEX] is resolving ok, while if I add it as watch expression - 'no such static field IDX_SOMEINDEX'. Even if I specify full path my.package.MyIndexesClass.IDX_SOMEINDEX Android Studio still doesn't know.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Just to check, are you sure that you're not making a minified build? You won't see some variables in the watch window if the build is minified.

Comment: Ha, this is could be the reason, I'm using proguard on QA build (using it as debug because non-debug signature is needed to debug IAP). Will check it out.

Comment: You'd write it as answer, I'll check it as a right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re probably using a minified build, that makes variable names disappear. If you turn off minifying, you should be able to see the variables.